# How do deleted LinkedIn contacts get removed from MacOS Apple AddressBook?

Tags: contacts, macos

I have been researching the connection between the MacOS Apple AddressBook and LinkedIn. The connector comes with MacOS and it appears to use the LinkedIn API.  The terms of service for the normal LinkedIn API allows users to download information *but not retain a copy*. If you wish to retain a copy, you need to sign up for a special LinkedIn program. It's reasonable to assume that Apple has signed up for that program.

Using the `ABAddressBook` framework, I am able to find all of the entries in my addressbook that come from LinkedIn. I cannot delete the AddressBook card from within the Apple AddressBook; when I have one of these cards selected, the DeleteCard option is not enabled.

So here is my question: I delete somebody from LinkedIn, and **they do not get deleted from my Apple AddressBook**. So how do they get deleted? Do they ever get deleted?

Comment: Have you checked with LinkedIn on how this works and how you can delete contacts?

Comment: It's easy to delete on LinkedIn using their web GUI. That's what I did above. "I delete somebody from LinkedIn, and they do not get deleted from my Apple AddressBook."

Comment: My question was about asking LinkedIn how you can delete their contacts from your address book, not deleting the contacts from within LinkedIn.

Comment: Typically in similar scenarios, any data fetched from API does not get updated locally. That means its likely that the contacts would remain in your Apple AddressBook even after deleting them from LinkedIn.

Comment: @NimeshNeema, that's only true of poorly designed synchronization systems.

Comment: I agree @vy32. Just stating that it could be a possibility.